# Accidentally sprayed the wrong product in my mouth

Tags: toxicity

I sprayed the wrong product in my mouth the other day. It was a spray hand cleaner. Noticed the mistake right away and immediately spit it out and then rinsed my mouth. But even so, my tongue and throat burned for a good 10 to 15 minutes afterwards. The label on the product lists the following ingredients but no % of concentrations is given:

- List item
  benzethonium chloride
  myristamine oxide
  polyquaternium 7
  deionised water
  fragrance

Again, the amount that I actually swallowed was infinitely small but I was surprised it burned that much. I would like to know your opinion if I should consult a doctor just the same. This happened 3 days ago and now feel pretty good, except for perhaps the occasional burning still in my tongue and throat. But the tongue looks good, no burning marks or anything like that that I can see.

Thanks for your time.